# Eclipse crashes with Problematic frame "C [libgtk-3.so.0+0x398e83] gtk_widget_hide+0x23" - Do I need update some library?

Tags: eclipse, crash, gtk, gtk3

I am running Eclipse 2021-09 under Java 16.0.2 on RHEL 8 Linux. It runs fine, but when doing some  (to me) arbitrary dialog operation I got a SIGSEGV with the Problematic frame:

```
C  [libgtk-3.so.0+0x398e83]  gtk_widget_hide+0x23
```

(The complete crash report can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Nj4cCNrQ))

Any idea what this crash might be caused by? Do I have to update some library? The necessary additional libraries are all installed via dnf/yum:

```
webkit2gtk3.x86_64       2.30.4-1.el8
webkit2gtk3-jsc.x86_64   2.30.4-1.el8
gtk2.x86_64              2.24.32-5.el8
gtk2-devel.x86_64        2.24.32-5.el8
gtk3.x86_64              3.22.30-6.el8
```